# Pull the correct version of an Android companion app from Play Store to match a Windows desktop version

Tags: android, google-play, publish, versioning

We are developing a windows desktop application that manages data. There is a companion mobile app that is used to collect that data. We would like to put this app on the Play store to make it easier for customers to download.

However, there is a problem. The Android app version number must match the desktop app version number. Some of our customers update their desktop software immediately and some wait years. I'm trying to come up with an approach to make sure our users somehow pull the correct Android app from the play store to match their current desktop software version.

Possible methods I've thought of:

1. Have the app downloaded from the Play Store only a portion of the final app, then have that app download the rest of the app as needed. I know that you can have an app download assets later, but I'm assuming you can't download executable code, so is something like this even possible?
2. Similar to the previous option but have an app that is more like a download manager to download other complete apps. I know this would require special privileges and probably be a lot of work?
3. Have major versions of the app that are non-breaking within each major version number. Publish each as their own separate app on the Play Store. This is not ideal as it adds complexity on our end and a messy experience on the Play Store.

Is there a clean way or an official method by Google or the community to handle a situation like this?

Comment: Google does not allow to select a specific version to be installed. AFAIK on recent versions of Android dynamic dex code loading at run-time is disallowed.

Comment: IMHO you can choose: make your app compatible with multiple desktop versions or simply provide an "installer app" in Play Store that connects to your desktop program, determines the required app version, downloads it from your server via HTTPS and installs it (requires user consent dialog).